# 3 div on the same line: the left and right change their width in function of the windows size while the centered is fixed

Tags: css, layout

Maybe it is really simple but I can't get it.

I'd like the center of my 3 columns to have 1280 width and have the other two resized in function of the size of the windows (so if, for instance, the window is 1280px large, I can't see the side divs).

Here is my code. Where am I wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>

div{display:block;}


#left{
    border:1px solid green;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    }
#center{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:1280px;
    float:left;
    }
#right{
    border:1px solid purple;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container_center">
        <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="center">
        Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave us the url of this so we do not have to load it on our own, but I would start by adding a `min-width:10px;` and a `min-height:100px`. Possible starting with some lorem ipsum because some browsers might ignore your space.